# Google Play Services availability and Google Play

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-services

We developed an application that uses the Google Play Services extension.

I assume that people without Google Play Services installed on their device side will not be able to use these services.
However if people does not have Google Play Services installed on their device, they probably cannot download it in the first place, because they dont have Google Play App itself.

So is it safe to assume that most people who install the app have Google Play Service installed and make a more general verification in our app for other rare cases?
For example, check if Google Play Services availability and if not installed, simply write a message and exit the app.

What is your opinion on that ?

Thanks

Comment: No it is not safe to assume that that without google play app there is no google play services installed. Also user's might have google play services but it is outdated so an update will be required. you can programmatically ask the user to update google play services and take them to the play store

Answer (score 1):

One of the things that can happen is that Google Play Services is present on the device, but not up to date. Or the user could have disabled Google Play Services. In both these cases connection to Google Play Services will fail, so you really have to check for it, no excuses :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found on [Android's developers website](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure)

> Important: Because it is hard to anticipate the state of each device, you must always check for a compatible Google Play services APK before you access Google Play services features. For many apps, the best time to check is during the onResume() method of the main activity.